# Make a sprite white in XNA 4.0 w/ simple shader (alpha issues)

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, shader, xna-4.0

Using the simple shader at [Tint Sprite White](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82914/how-can-i-tint-a-sprite-to-white-in-xna) and the sample code at [Sprite Effects Sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/sprite_effects), I've loaded the .fx file for the shader into the sample project and replaced one of the sample effects in one of the Draw() calls to use the whitening effect.

What I get is a big white square with the same dimensions as the texture itself. I obviously want only the regions of the texture where the alpha is not 0 to be made white. The shader appears to be working, as I altered the default white color to other test cases and the square does change color.

I tried this in a simple project of my own and got the same result. How can I make sure that only the visible part of the texture is shaded?

The modified call looks like this:

```
        spriteBatch.Begin(0, null, null, null, null, whiteEffect);

        spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, CenterOnScreen(myTexture), Color.White);

        spriteBatch.End();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, double-check to make sure you have alpha in your image.

That shader assumes you're using non-premultiplied alpha:

```
batch.Begin(0, BlendState.NonPremultiplied, null, null, null, whiteEffect);
```

The shader uses the texture's alpha value as a base for the whitening; in other words, the more solid the alpha, the more solid the whitening effect. If you don't want any "in-betweens" (e.g. partially white), it will work if your texture has no "in-between" alpha in it.

### Non-premultiplied Partial-White Alpha (Original) Version

```
   float4 ps_main( PS_INPUT Input ) : COLOR0
   {
       float4 color = tex2D( baseMap, Input.Texcoord );
       return float4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, color.a);
   }
```

EDIT: Since a premultiplied version was inquired about, I'll add that version in with an explanation.

From [this helpful article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/11/06/premultiplied-alpha.aspx):

> To convert a non premultiplied color into premultiplied format:
>
> color.rgb *= color.a

So let's do the same here in our shader:

### Premultiplied Partial-White Alpha Version

```
   float4 ps_main( PS_INPUT Input ) : COLOR0
   {
       float4 color = tex2D( baseMap, Input.Texcoord );
       return float4(color.a, color.a, color.a, color.a);
   }
```

Now you can go ahead and use the default alpha blend state:

```
batch.Begin(0, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null, whiteEffect);
```

I'm still not really sure if you want the hard "white or transparent" ... in that case it doesn't really matter if you do pre-multiplied or not because you could just do a "boolean" style return of pure white (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) or pure transparent (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); these particular colors will both show up the same regardless of blend state:

### Hard White-or-Transparent (Ignores partial whites), Premultiplied-Agnostic

```
float4 ps_main( PS_INPUT Input ) : COLOR0
{
   float4 color = tex2D( baseMap, Input.Texcoord );
   if (color.a > 0.0f)
   {
      return float4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
   }
   else
   {
      return float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked nicely. I'll need to look into premultiplied alpha vs. non-pre (noticed other questions about this issue in XNA 4.0). How would the shader code be changed to assume one is using premultiplied alpha?