# C# XNA How do I set a Texture2D to a single color?

Tags: c#, colors, xna, sprite, textures

How do I set every non transparent pixel in an arbitrary Texture2D to let's say Color.White temporarily?

Comment: Do you mean you want to actually change the texture? Or just draw it as white? If you're drawing you can use a shader, [check out this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598832/make-a-sprite-white-in-xna-4-0-w-simple-shader-alpha-issues/9600620#9600620), note that it references an external shader, but it's not too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a conditional loop? This won't be exact syntax for it, but something among the lines of:

```
Texture2D texture = /*copy the texture you want to change*/;
Pixel pixel;/*note it's really inexact, so don't mind it, the idea is to show how it would be done*/
for(int i=0; i<texture.width; i++)
{
  for(int j=0; j<texture.height; j++)
  {
    pixel = texture.GetPixel(i, j);
    if(pixel.Color.A==1)
      pixel.Color = Color.White;
  }
}
```

I cannot stress this enough: do NOT just copy paste this in, this is similar to pseudocode, just there to show how it would be done.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this, but out of my head, you could do something like this:

```
  Color[] az = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => Color.White).ToArray();
  Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(GameRef.GraphicsDevice, 10, 10, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
  texture.SetData(az);
```

This first creates an array with 100 elements, and fills it with Color.White
Then using the SetData, we fill it with the colorarray.

Just make sure the array is the same size as the texture size (height*width)

Comment: OP didn't want to set *every* pixel, just the opaque ones